# Why won't my service start as local system?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-service

I have a service on a Windows Server 2k8 machine. If I set it to logon as local system, it won't start. Event logs show error 7000 and 7009 (both timeouts).

If I set it to logon as a local administrator account, I can start it manually. But it won't start automatically if I restart the server (I have startup type set to automatic).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this something you wrote, or a third-party application? If third-party, what is it?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you are necessarily doing anything wrong. Sounds like another service it depends on hasn't fully started yet. It is possible that any dependencies are not configured at all. It also appears that the service requires full admin to run.

As a workaround, I would configure the service properties this way:

1. On the **Log On** tab, use the local
   administrator account.
2. On the **Recovery** tab, change the first
   and second failure events to restart
   the service.

It's not the most elegant solution, but if it's purely an issue due to permissions and timing, this should resolve it.

Comment: At the very least it will confirm if the theory is correct, and give you a jumping off point for further troubleshooting, so take a mark up. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth looking in gpedit.msc and checking out the Computer Config | Windows Settings | Security Settings | Local Policies | User Rights Assignment | Deny log on as a service and Log on as a service entries.